# Operating system computations for throughput

Tags: operating-system

Can i get help with this? I can't seem to understand the question

"In this problem you are to compare reading a file using a single-threaded file server with a multi- threaded file server. It takes 16 msec to get a request for work, dispatch it, and do the rest of the necessary processing, assuming the data are in the block cache. If a disk operation is needed (assume a spinning disk drive with 1 head), as is the case one-fourth of the time, an additional 32 msec is required."

Answer (score 0):

> Can i get help with this?

I don't think so (I don't think there's enough information in the question for anyone to be able to understand it).

**Example 1**

The file server is single-threaded and handles asynchronous requests, and the "16 msec" is primarily "request delivery latency" (time between a process sending a request and the file server receiving the request). A process sends a single request asking to read from 1000 files, the file server receives this request, "immediately" sends back 750 replies (for file data that was cached) and sends a single request asking something (file system code, disk driver?) to fetch the remaining 250 things; then file server "immediately" waits for more requests while waiting for the reply from something (file system code, disk driver?) to complete the early 250 things. In this case you can say that throughput for single-threaded file server is virtually infinite (e.g. infinite throughput for "file data cache hit", which is the only thing that matters because you can make more requests while waiting for slow disk IO).

**Example 2**

The file server has 8 threads and handles synchronous requests. A single-threaded process sends 1 request (to read from 1 file) and then has to wait for the reply, the request is given to one of the file server's threads (doesn't matter which) and that thread takes an average of "16 + 32*0.25 = 24 msec" for the request to be handled before the process can make it's next request; and the process does this in a loop because it wants to read 1000 files. In this case throughput is "1/0.024 = 41.66 requests per second", which is extremely bad (primarily because the single-threaded process can't send requests fast enough to keep all threads of the multi-threaded server busy).

**Example 3**

The file server has 8 threads and handles synchronous requests. A process with 1000 threads send 1 request (to read from 1 file) from each of its threads. In this case we need to know how many CPUs there are (and how scheduler works) to determine anything about throughput. E.g. if there's only 2 CPUs then you're not going to get 8 file server threads running in parallel at the same time.